# select2 load data using ajax cannot select any option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have the following code (javascript):

```
$('#cbxConnections').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    multiple: false,
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder:{
        text:"@Diccionario.Connections",
        id:" @Diccionario.Connections"
    },
    ajax:{
        url:'@Url.Action("GetActiveConnections","Admin")',
        dataType: 'json',
        type:'post',
        data:function(params){
            return {
                q: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data,page){
            return {
                results: data
            };
        }
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { 
        return markup; 
    },
    templateResult: function(response){
        return '<div>'+response.Name+'</div>';
    },
    templateSelection: function(response){
        return response.Id;
    },
    id: function(connection){
       console.log(connection);
    }
});
```

For the server side I am using ASP MVC 4.
The select get data using ajax and render the options but this options are not selectable.
Reading other posts, they describe using the id function, but this function appearently desappears on the version of select2 I'm using 2.4

I'm following the example of ajax on the documentation showing on [github](http://select2.github.io/examples.html)
**"Loading remote data"**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to select a result from the select2 search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933830/unable-to-select-a-result-from-the-select2-search-results)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If your ajax response doesn't have **id** and **text** attributes you should fix them client side

This is a requirement on version 4.0 (don't know why)

```
ajax: {

   processResults: function (data, params) {

                params.page = params.page || 1;

                // you should map the id and text attributes on version 4.0

                var select2Data = $.map(data.result.data, function (obj) {
                    obj.id = obj._id.$id;
                    obj.text = obj.name;

                    return obj;
                });

                return {
                    results: select2Data,
                    pagination: {
                        more: data.result.more
                    }
                };
            }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks ! helped a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Perfect as I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that I could not unselect option (it was a select multiple) and the problem was that I passed id as an number, but it should be string

```
var select2Data = $.map(data.result.data, function (obj) {
    obj.id = '' + obj._id.$id; //small fix
    obj.text = obj.name;

    return obj;
});
```