# Select2 Ajax can't select options being pulled in from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use the data in my API to populate a select input. I'm using Select2 and have everything working but am unable to select anything once results are found. I'll post my code below, I've been working on this for over 12 hours and can't find anything on the internet that works or even helps to get closer.

HTML:

```
<select id="school_input"></select>
```

Select2 Setup:

```
function formatResults (results) {
    if (results.loading) return "Searching...";
    var markup = "<div class='select2-result'>" + results.school_name + "</div>";
    return markup;
}

$('#school_input').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "http://services.url.com/services/globalopponentlookup.ashx",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        school_name: params.term, 
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
      return {
        results: data.schools,
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  templateResult: formatResults
});
```

Example of data being pulled in from API:

```
jQuery31101273177236076506_1487863085363({
  "schools": [
    {
      "school_search_keywords": "florida",
      "website": "http://www.cf.edu/",
      "school_id": "1514",
      "school_name": "Central Florida Community College",
      "school_website": "http://www.cf.edu/",
      "school_location": "Ocala, FL ",
      "school_mascot": "Patriots",
      "school_logo_file": "CFpats.png",
      "conference_id": "155",
      "school_last_updated": "2/26/2014 9:23:51 AM",
      "school_zip": "34474",
      "school_ncaa_code": "0",
      "school_abbrev": null,
      "logo": "http://clients.url.com/files/logos/njcaa/CFpats.png",
      "colors_id": null,
      "url": null,
      "safe_text_white": null,
      "safe_text_black": null,
      "primary_background": null,
      "primary_text": null,
      "secondary_background": null,
      "secondary_text": null,
      "client_id": null,
      "created": null,
      "deleted": null
    },
    {
      "school_search_keywords": "florida",
      "website": "http://www.easternflorida.edu/athletics/",
      "school_id": "2521",
      "school_name": "Eastern Florida State College",
      "school_website": "http://www.easternflorida.edu/athletics/",
      "school_location": "Cocoa, FL",
      "school_mascot": "Titans",
      "school_logo_file": "Eastern-Florida-State.png",
      "conference_id": "155",
      "school_last_updated": "1/19/2016 4:03:58 PM",
      "school_zip": "32922",
      "school_ncaa_code": null,
      "school_abbrev": "EFSC",
      "logo": "http://clients.url.com/files/logos/njcaa/Eastern-Florida-State.png",
      "colors_id": null,
      "url": null,
      "safe_text_white": null,
      "safe_text_black": null,
      "primary_background": null,
      "primary_text": null,
      "secondary_background": null,
      "secondary_text": null,
      "client_id": null,
      "created": null,
      "deleted": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to select a result from the select2 search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933830/unable-to-select-a-result-from-the-select2-search-results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to have Id value in the JSON in order to make it selectable. https://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/Lqso63mw/2/**

**JS**

```
function formatResults (results) {
    if (results.loading) return "Searching...";
    var markup = "<div class='select2-result'>" + results.school_name + "</div>";
    return markup;
}

function formatRepoSelection (results) {
      return results.school_name;
}

$('#school_input').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/15d345",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        school_name: params.term, 
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
        $(data.schools).each(function(){
        this.id=this.school_id;
      });
      return {
        results: data.schools,
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  templateResult: formatResults,
  templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});
```

[image]

Comment: The link is working now but I'm still unable to select anything in the dropdown.

Comment: @JoeScotto Type 4 letters atleast it returns the data on search.

Comment: Yes, but my issue is that I cannot select any of the values. I can get the select to populate just fine.

Comment: @JoeScotto Try the updated fiddle. It's mandatory to have Id field in the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your markup from the `formatResults()` function :

```
function formatResults (results) {
  if (results.loading) return "Searching...";
  return "<div class='select2-result'>" + results.school_name + "</div>";  
}
```

See the [documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html#can-i-change-how-the-placeholder-looks)

Comment: My bad, my actual code has `return markup;`, see updated question. I tried what you have and still get the same issue where once results are found, I cannot select any of them.